# Key value in linked list is being trashed

Tags: c, hash, linked-list

I am writing a program that traverses the directory system, creates hash values for the files that are found, then if any other files with the same hash key(duplicate files) are found they are grouped together. I am planning on using a linked list embedded in another linked list. The top-level linked list contains the hash key, and then the nodes associated with that key contain the values of files that are duplicates. Currently, I am getting stuck trying initializing the top-level list. I pass the first key value successfully to the linked list, creating the `headList`. However, after the initial pass and continuing on with the traversal, the value of the key is lost and I am unsure why. I tracked it down using gdb and found that the value is deleted somewhere when I go back into the `searchDirects` function.

Here is my code:

```
 #define _GNU_SOURCE // for asprintf(), if needed
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <dirent.h> 
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <openssl/md5.h>

    //stat -c "%s %n" filename
    //The above will display filename and size of file

    //gcc -g -Wall -o file file.c -lssl -lcrypto
    //the above is needed to link libraries so the encryption will work

    #define table_size 20
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 4096 //max path buffer size
    #define X (37)

    void directoryCheck(char *fileName, char *dirValue);

    //This will be the struct that contains the binned hash keys (the rows)
    struct LinkNode {
        char pathValue[BUFFER_SIZE]; // this will be used to hold the directory value
        struct LinkNode *nextNode;
    };

    struct List {
        struct LinkNode *headNode; // Embedded linked list
        unsigned char *key; // Hash key value
        struct List *nextList;
        //char *value;
    }*headList;


    void printAllThatShit(struct List **headList)
    {
        struct List *temp;
        temp = *headList;

        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Here is the key when sent to print function:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                printf("%02x", temp->key[i]);
            printf("\n");
            temp = temp->nextList;
        }

    }
    //Function to add to List
    void addToList(unsigned char *key, char* dirValue)
    {

        //head is Null, so we will put first key in
        if(headList == NULL)
        {
            printf("Adding to head of list!\n");
            headList = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
            headList->nextList = NULL;
            headList->key = key;
            /*printf("Here is the key: %s\n", headList->key);
            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                printf("%02x", headList->key[i]);
            printf(" %s\n", dirValue);*/

        }
        else
        {    
           currentList = headList;

            if(currentList != 0)
           {

                while(currentList->nextList != 0)
                {
                    if(currentList->key == key)
                    {
                        printf("Found the same key!\n");
                        return;
                    }
                    currentList = currentList->nextList;
                }
                currentList->nextList = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
                currentList = currentList->nextList;
                currentList->key = key;
                currentList->nextList = NULL;

            } 
        }

        printAllThatShit(&headList); //After this initial print    
                                     //with headList, the key value is junked

    }

    void deleteList(struct List **headList)
    {
        struct List *current, *next;
        current = *headList;

        while(current != NULL)
        {
            printf("Here is the current value: %s", current->key);
            next = current->nextList;
            free(current);
            current = next;
        }

        *headList = NULL;
    }


    void md5Hash(char *path)
    {
        unsigned char key[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; //16 bytes for the output
        struct stat statbuf;
        FILE *inFile;
        MD5_CTX mdx;
        int bytes, i, size;        

        stat(path, &statbuf);
        size = statbuf.st_size;

        inFile = fopen(path, "rb");

        /*if(size == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s", File);
            return;
        }*/ 


        if(inFile == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s", path);
            return;
        }

        unsigned char data[size];

        //Initialize the structure
        MD5_Init(&mdx);
        //fread read the file byte-by-byte for 1024 bytes, and reads it into
        //the buffer(data). The function returns how many bytes that were
        //successfully read. Then, MD5_Update hashes and updates the structure using
        //the bytes in the data buffer, and goes in 1 byte increments.
        while((bytes = fread(data, 1, size, inFile)) != 0)
            MD5_Update(&mdx, data, bytes);
        MD5_Final(key, &mdx); //Place the final 16 byte output in key

        for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
            printf("%02x", key[i]);
        printf(" %s\n", path);

        fclose(inFile);

        printf("Here is that file path while in the hashing function: %s\n", path);
        addToList(key, path);


    }


    void newFile(char *fileName, char *dirValue)
    {
        printf("Made it to add a new file!\n");
        char *appendPath = NULL;

        asprintf(&appendPath,"%s/%s", dirValue, fileName);

        printf("Here is that file you are now sending to be Hashed: %s\n", fileName);

        md5Hash(appendPath);




    }




    //CHeck if the argument is a file
    int is_regular_file(const char *path)
    {
        struct stat path_stat;
        stat(path, &path_stat);
        return S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode);
    }

    void searchDirects(char *path, int depth)
    {
        DIR *dp; // represents directory stream
        struct dirent *entry; // This is used for traversing directories
        struct stat statbuf; // this is so you can use the stat()
        int file;

        stat(path, &statbuf);


        dp = opendir(path);
        if(dp)
        {
            while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
            {
                if(entry->d_type == DT_REG)
                { 
                    printf("Found a file in the directory!\n");
                    newFile(entry->d_name, path); //send the file name and directory to be added
                }
                else if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Found files with . or ..!\n");
                    continue; 
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Attempting to check a directory\n");
                    directoryCheck(entry->d_name, path); 
                }
                printf("[%s]\n", entry->d_name);

            }
            closedir(dp);
        }


    }

    void directoryCheck(char *fileName, char *dirValue)
    {
        char *appendPath;


        asprintf(&appendPath,"%s/%s", dirValue, fileName);


        searchDirects(appendPath, 1);


        free(appendPath);
    }

    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        headList = NULL;
        //headNode = NULL;
        //struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(20 * sizeof(struct node));

        if(argc <= 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int i = 0;
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if(is_regular_file(argv[i]))
            {    
                printf("Put function to handle file\n");
                //getHashKey(argv[i]);
                md5Hash(argv[i]);
            }    
            else
                searchDirects(argv[i], 1);   
        }


        printAllThatShit(&headList);
        printf("Going to delete the list now!\n");
        deleteList(&headList); 

        printf("Scan of current directory:\n");
        printf("Scan of current directory: %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("done.\n");
        //free(newnode);
        exit(0);


    }
```

I am aware that I have many different errors, and most likely memory leaks at this point. However, I am just trying to figure out why the key value is being lost in the headList->key after the initial pass. And, any subsequent passes the key is lost for added nodes. I thought it may because the way I am creating the hash key and passing it, but then when I ran gdb I realized the key is lost when I go back to the while() searching the directories (as I mentioned above). Thanks for any help or insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by a common error. In `addToList`:

```
headList->key = key;
```

That creates a pointer to the `key` buffer. However, `addToList` is called this way in the `md5Hash` function:

```
unsigned char key[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
addToList(key, path);
```

In that code `key` is a local variable. It goes out of scope when the `md5Hash` function exits. And hence the linked list `key` field is an invalid pointer. All bets are off at that point as accessing memory from an invalid pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

One fix is to `memcpy` the key value into the linked list.

Define `key` as an array instead of a pointer.

```
struct List {
    struct LinkNode *headNode; // Embedded linked list
    unsigned char key[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // Hash key value
    struct List *nextList;
    //char *value;
}*headList;
```

In `addToList`:

```
// REMOVE THIS LINE:
// headList->key = key; 

// REPLACE WITH THIS:
memcpy(headList->key, key, sizeof(headList->key));
```

Comment: Thank you! I used strcpy() instead - mostly because I have used it before and have a better understanding of how it works. However, you pointing out my initial problem at the top made complete sense. I did make the key an array as you suggested too, thanks again!

Comment: @MuffinMan1042 I strongly advise against using `strcpy`. I specifically did not use that. Because I think `key` as set by the MD5 lib functions is *not* a string. Using string functions may appear to work but is Undefined Behaviour and is just waiting to fail.

Comment: Okay, I will use memcpy as you have suggested. Thanks, again!